# Get any user_id from Facebook url

Tags: php, facebook-graph-api

Can I get any user id from facebook url with PHP language?

Facebook graph api not allow get any user info. Is there another way to get info without access_token?

Comment: Why would need just the user_id?

Comment: Not only user_id, I just want to see json profile data from any facebook url.
Are there permissions of graph facebook api to do this?

Comment: what for? data of users is none of your business, if the user did not specifically authorize it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot get any Facebook's User data using the Facebook API without the User's explicit permission. The permission is granted to you (your APP) by the user in a popup window stating exactly what information you are receiving and with which permission type (read, write etc..)

This is all for good reasons.

Comment: Thank you. So can we try other ways without using Facebook API?

Comment: You can try but it is not ethical and probably not legal. Not to mention that both you and FB will be in contravention on GDPR if you somehow manage.

Comment: we will definitely not help you do something that is not allowed. the only thing we can tell you is: don't do it. be a honest developer, not one of the "bad guys". we don't like bad guys. no one does.

Comment: I just want to test Facebook API for my examination, not for business. If it's impossible, I won't try anymore.

Comment: Thanks, @StellarNguyen. I understand we have to look into all possibilities. Please understand that it is not only because it is not possible but because devs should not be involved in this kind of work. I'm not saying you are trying to carry out an illegal activity but simply that this one will be. I'm positive your question is legitimate and that you are testing out all possibilities for your software requirements. I think my answer answers your question. Kindly mark it as so.

Comment: Ok. Sorry about my question wasn't clearly and make everyone misunderstand about me.

Comment: It's okay. Please accept my answer as it answers your question :)